# Tcl set variable by concatenate a command and string

Tags: tcl, variable-declaration

I am trying to set a variable like this

```
puts [lindex $bar 0]  # prints bar0
set foo $[lindex $bar 0]_someString
```

But printing the foo variable not getting the value in foo:

```
puts $foo  # prints $bar0_someString
# but I want the value in bar0_someString varialbe
# not the variable name.
```

Is this a syntax error? Is it a bad coding style to declare a variable? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
set foo [expr $[lindex $bar 0]_someString]
```

A running example:

```
% set bar {a b c}
a b c
% set a_someString tttttt
tttttt
% set foo [expr $[lindex $bar 0]_someString]
tttttt
% puts $foo
tttttt
```

Comment: Edited my questions, I want the value in bar0_someString varialbe, not the variable name.

Comment: This is an _antipattern_, one of the few things we really recommend not doing in Tcl. Use @slebetman's answer instead, which is both much faster and safer.

Answer (score 5):

Remember that `$x` is just a shortcut for `set x`. So you can also do this:

```
set foo [set [lindex $bar 0]_someString]
```

Comment: The double quotes aren't necessary; Tcl doesn't get confused by such things.

Comment: Ah.. yes. I blame it on too much bash programming :-). Edited my answer - thanks.